# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node when manually creating search in data tables

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a ReactJS application, and I'm facing an issue on a particular page where I load data from my table and display it using DataTables.

Previously, I had a search feature that worked perfectly. However, after integrating DataTables into the page, I'm encountering an error. When I type in the search box, I receive the following error message: "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node." I am aware that Data Tables has a search box but I rather not use it.

From my research, I think that this error is related to redrawing the DataTable, so when I type to search, there's an issue showing what to filter out, but I'm struggling to find a solution. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Please see my code below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { KTIcon } from "../../../../_metronic/helpers";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import $ from "jquery";
import "datatables.net";
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
import { FaEye } from "react-icons/fa";

interface Driver {
  DriverID: string;
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
  Address: string;
  ContactNumber: string;
}

const DriverList: React.FC = () => {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState<Driver[]>([]);
  const [filterType, setFilterType] = useState<string>("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>("");
  const tableRef = useRef<HTMLTableElement | null>(null);
  const dataTableRef = useRef<DataTables.Api | null>(null);

  const fetchDrivers = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/getDrivers");
      setDrivers(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching drivers:", error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDrivers = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/getDrivers");
        setDrivers(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching drivers:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchDrivers();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // initializeDataTables();
  }, [drivers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tableRef.current) {
      if (dataTableRef.current) {
        // Destroy the previous DataTable instance
        dataTableRef.current.destroy();
      }

      // Initialize the DataTable
      const dataTable = $(tableRef.current).DataTable({
        paging: true,
        lengthChange: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        searching: true,
        data: drivers,
        columns: [
          { data: "DriverID" },
          { data: "FirstName" },
          { data: "LastName" },
          { data: "Address" },
          { data: "ContactNumber" },
          {
 
            data: null,
            render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
              return `
                <a href="/crafted/account/drivers/${row.DriverID}" class="btn btn-icon btn-bg-light btn-active-color-primary btn-sm me-1">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-eye fs-3"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="/crafted/account/driversEdit/${row.DriverID}" class="btn btn-icon btn-bg-light btn-active-color-primary btn-sm me-1">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil fs-3"></i>
                `;
            },
          },
        ],
      });

      dataTableRef.current = dataTable;
    }
  }, [drivers]);

  const filterDrivers = () => {
 
    if (!filterType) {
      return drivers;  
    }

    const filteredDrivers = drivers.filter((driver) => {
      if (filterType === "DriverID") {
        return driver.DriverID.toLowerCase().includes(
          searchValue.toLowerCase()
        );
      }
      if (filterType === "FirstName") {
        return driver.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(
          searchValue.toLowerCase()
        );
      }
      if (filterType === "LastName") {
        return driver.LastName.toLowerCase().includes(
          searchValue.toLowerCase()
        );
      }
     
      return true;  
    });

    return filteredDrivers;
  };

  return (
    <div className="card mb-5 mb-xl-8">
      <div className="card-header border-0 pt-5">
        <h3 className="card-title align-items-start flex-column">
          <span className="card-label fw-bold fs-3 mb-1">Drivers</span>
          <span className="text-muted mt-1 fw-semibold fs-7">
            List of Drivers
          </span>
        </h3>
        <div className="card-toolbar">
          <select
            className="form-select"
            style={{ width: "200px", paddingLeft: "10px" }}
            value={filterType}
            onChange={(e) => setFilterType(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="">Select Search Value</option>
            <option value="DriverID">Driver ID</option>
            <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
            <option value="LastName">Last Name</option>
          </select>
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "10px" }}>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              style={{ width: "200px", paddingLeft: "10px" }}
              placeholder="Search..."
              value={searchValue}
              onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "10px" }}>
            <button
              className="btn btn-sm btn btn-primary hover-scale"
              onClick={fetchDrivers}
            >
              <i className="ki-duotone ki-magnifier fs-2">
                <span className="path1"></span>
                <span className="path2"></span>
              </i>
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "10px" }}>
            <Link
              to="/crafted/account/profile"
              className="btn btn-sm btn btn-primary hover-scale"
            >
              <KTIcon iconName="plus" className="fs-2" />
              Add New Driver
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="card-body py-3">
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table align-middle gs-0 gy-4" ref={tableRef}>
            <thead>
              <tr className="fw-bold text-muted bg-light">
                <th>Driver ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact Number</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {filterDrivers().map((driver, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{driver.DriverID}</td>
                  <td>{driver.FirstName}</td>
                  <td>{driver.LastName}</td>
                  <td>{driver.Address}</td>
                  <td>{driver.ContactNumber}</td>
          
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DriverList;
```

`